# C++: set fill after printing out a string

Tags: c++, string, cout, fill

I'm trying to `cout` a string so that the total length of the output is, say 15.

For example, if the string is "Tom", then I want 12 spaces after `cout`. I know how to use `setfill` and `setw` to have leading spaces, but is there a built-in way of filling spaces afterwards? Or the only way to do this is to get the string length and append a bunch of space at the end of the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) output modifier.

```
#include <iomanip>    // std::setw
#include <ios>        // std::left
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string

int
main()
{
  const std::string words[] = {
    "Tom",
    "Ferdinand",
    "And finally some longer string",
  };
  for (const auto& w : words)
    std::cout << std::setw(12) << std::left << w << "|\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Tom         |
Ferdinand   |
And finally some longer string|
```

Comment: Would it be better to note that (or am I wrong that) header `iostream`, which gives us `cout`, aleady includes header `ios`?

Comment: @NickyC It might do that on your implementation but as far as I know, the standard doesn't say it has to so you cannot rely on it.

Comment: Lately, looking up cppreference.com and N4527, `iso` seems to be included by `iostream` since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Use IO manipulator `std::left` defined in header `ios`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to cout a string so that the total length of the output is,
>   say 15. For example, if the string is "Tom", then I want 12 spaces
>   after cout.

I have used the following ...

```
// ...
{
    std::stringstream ss1;
    ss1 << "Tom"; // insert 
    const int NameFieldSize = 15;
    while (ss1.str().size() < NameFieldSize) ss << " ";
    // ... insert the rest of the info to ss1
    // now write the full string to cout (or file)
    std::cout << ss1.str() << std::endl;
}
// ...
```

stringstream works just like cout, all the formatting controls, but because it is ram based, much faster.

Note that when ss1 is already longer than NameFieldSize, the code and detect and then possibly 'fix' the output format.